Extract certain dictionary values from a list of dictionaries in Pandas dataframe
I have a dataframe (table) where one column consists of a list of dictionary key-values
| Trip number | location                                                                | airlines
| ----------- | ----------------------------------------------------------------------- | --------
| 13452       | [{'Name': 'Japan', 'City': 'Tokyo', 'Continent': 'Asia'},               | British Airways
|             | {'Name': 'United Kingdom',  'City': 'London', 'Continent': 'Europe'},   |
|             | {'Name': 'Australia', 'City': 'Sydney', 'Continent': 'Australia'}]      |

| 13567       | [{'Name': 'China', 'City': 'Hong Kong', 'Continent': 'Asia'},           |Emirates
|             | {'Name': 'India', 'City': 'Calcutta', 'Continent': 'Asia'}]             |

| 13768       | [{'Name': 'France', 'City': 'Paris', 'Continent': 'Europe'},            |Air France
|             | {'Name': 'Italy', 'City': 'Rome', 'Continent': 'Europe'},               |
|             | {'Name': 'Egypt', 'City': 'Cairo', 'Continent': 'Africa'}]              |


I want to produce the below dataframe (table) where the values for certain keys, in this case 'Name' are left.



Trip number
location
airlines




13452
Japan, United Kingdom, Australia
British Airways


13567
China, India
Emirates


13768
France', Italy, Egypt
Air France



I think I need to use a list comprehension method to solve this:
df['location'] = [d.get('Name') for d in df['location']] 

Or create a new 'name' column:
df['name'] = [[d.get('Name') for d in x] for x in df['location']]

I get an error with these though:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'


The implication of your AttributeError is probably that you do not have proper lists with dictionaries. If you would, [[d.get('Name') for d in x] for x in df['location']] should work just fine. Instead, what you have are string representations of lists. Try from ast import literal_eval and then: df['name'] = [[d.get('Name') for d in x] for x in df['location'].apply(literal_eval)].

It would be helpful if you could add your data sample via df.to_dict(), to know for sure what we're dealing with.

You can apply() a lambda function, ', '.join([d['Name'] for d in x], and join the locations in the location column:
import pandas as pd

D = {
    'Trip number': [13452, 13567, 13768],
    'location': [
        [{'Name': 'Japan', 'City': 'Tokyo', 'Continent': 'Asia'},
         {'Name': 'United Kingdom', 'City': 'London', 'Continent': 'Europe'},
         {'Name': 'Australia', 'City': 'Sydney', 'Continent': 'Australia'}],
        [{'Name': 'China', 'City': 'Hong Kong', 'Continent': 'Asia'},
         {'Name': 'India', 'City': 'Calcutta', 'Continent': 'Asia'}],
        [{'Name': 'France', 'City': 'Paris', 'Continent': 'Europe'},
         {'Name': 'Italy', 'City': 'Rome', 'Continent': 'Europe'},
         {'Name': 'Egypt', 'City': 'Cairo', 'Continent': 'Africa'}]
    ],
    'airlines': ['British Airways', 'Emirates', 'Air France']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(D)
df['location'] = df['location'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([d['Name'] for d in x]))

print(df)



Prints
   Trip number                          location         airlines
0        13452  Japan, United Kingdom, Australia  British Airways
1        13567                      China, India         Emirates
2        13768              France, Italy, Egypt       Air France



From what I gather, that solution is pretty close, except OP would like cities as a list of strings, not as a joint string? As the attempt at a comprehension suggests.

Also, the OP's own second attempt ([[d.get('Name') for d in x] for x in df['location']]) should have worked, if this is the df. OP probably has string representations.

@OCa Feel free to edit the answer with your comment.

@ouroboros1 Feel free to edit the answer with your comment.

well given @ouroboros1's comment, next step is rather that OP shares their df.to_dict(), so as to clear uncertainties regarding  input data dtype
